# How can i set my state by adding storage items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a todo list project by using react and redux. I managed to send my todo's id and itself to the local storage. Now I am trying to load my storages to UI when I open the site by using componentDidMount life cycle method.

However, I can send just one of the storage items which is the last one in the storage array to my state. How can I handle this situation ?

Here are my codes:

```
getElementsFromStorage = () => {
    let elements;

    if (localStorage.getItem('elements') === null) {
        elements = [];
    } else {
        elements = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('elements'))
    } return elements
}

componentDidMount() {
    const elements = this.getElementsFromStorage();

    elements.forEach(element => {
        this.setState({
            storageHolder: [...this.state.storageHolder, element]
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: The initial `this.state.storageHolder` will be an empty array, right? So why not simply: `this.setState({ storageHolder: elements })`? If you do want to append you have to use a function: `this.setState(state => ({ storageHolder: [...state.storageHolder, element] }))` (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged)

Comment: Thank you so much bro. I couldn't think it in this way I don't know why xD. Now it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Can u show console of `localStorage.getItem('elements')`?

Comment: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "AuV-A5w3fY2SITwZgQCKI", todo: "todo1"}
1: {id: "vik8wkoXbp8PsIoP03QhI", todo: "todo2"}
2: {id: "7RjfAtrZNjppKey1Bai98", todo: "todo3"}
3: {id: "gQuurimxDkFeWeKs2Scy1", todo: "todo4"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I did

```
this.setState({ storageHolder: elements })
```

it worked.